# kube-dns service unreliable on one master only

Tags: dns, kubernetes

We have a third-party software running on Kubernetes with three master and three worker nodes. For some time we have had a weird problem where pods seem to randomly have problems connecting other servers (outside of Kuberenetes) within the same network. We have had a lot of discussions with the software provider, but honestly I feel their offshore people have no clue and are just inventing workarounds that are not related to the actual root cause, so we started to investigate further ourselves.

Summarizing our own research it seems that the problem is somehow related to kube-dns service being unreliable on a single master node. This conclusion is based on the following facts we have learned by testing to ping a specific server within the network. In problematic cases the ping has variable response time and often fails completely.

**Fact 1: The problem exists only on one of our master nodes**
It is easily seen that pinging the server is unstable only on pods running on a single master and this can be seen far back in tbe logs.

**Fact 2: The problem exists only inside Kubernetes pods**
On the master node itself there are no problems.

**Fact 3: The problem is related to host resolving**
In a problematic pod, pinging with ip works fine, but pinging with hostname is unstable.

**Fact 4: The problem is not in the coredns pods**
Normally the pods have the ip of the kube-dns service in their /etc/resolv.conf. We have tested to replace this with the ips of each of the coredns pods one at a time and with all of those pinging works fine. it is only unstable when using the service as nameserver.

**Fact 5: Restaring pods and/or server seems to have no effect**
We have restarted the servers ond pods several times and the problem remains.

With these observings I tried to learn more about the Kubernetes services, but I struggle to find anything being wrong. I assume that a service configuration issue should break all the masters and not just one, so that seems to be ruled out. The kube-proxy is running on each node and handles services so I checked the logs, but didn't find any differences between the nodes. I also checked what iptables-save prints out for the ip of our kube-dns service, but it is identical between the nodes. Somehow I feel that with a node-specific problem on a service the kube-proxy should be my prime suspect, but can't figure out how to find any problem with it.

Does anyone have an idea where I should continue to dig more information on what is going on on that master node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting the following system parameters:

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
```

These had once been set, but something had happened since and these were in various states in different servers in the cluster.